# Error :Unknown type name BOOL for c function in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode

I am building a static library which has some c functions (both .h and .m file) with return type bool, after adding it to my existing project I am getting **Unknown Type name 'BOOL'**.
I tried importing stdbool.h but still I am getting same error.So can someone tell me right way to add c functions in Xcode project.The method definition looks like

```
BOOL isDeviceWorkingFine();
```

Comment: Try including `<Foundation/Foundation.h>`.

Comment: wow that was quick and bang on answer. Thanks you very very much.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev Sir, It seems OP needs the solution provided by you. I have copied your solution as a part of my answer, to make it complete. Hope you don't mind. :-)

Answer (score 6):

In `stdbool.h`, the definition is provided as `bool` which is a MACRO which gets expanded to `_Bool`. The `BOOL` you're using is not standard `C`.

If you want to use the standard definition provided by `stdbool.h`, you may want to change the `BOOL` to `bool`.

Otherwise, you need to use some other specific header file, which actually provides the definition of `BOOL` for your implementation.<sup>NOTE</sup>

---

NOTE: [as mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31454994/error-unknown-type-name-bool-for-c-function-in-xcode/31455129#comment50877152_31454994) by [Mr  Blagovest Buyukliev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265804/blagovest-buyukliev), you may need `<Foundation/Foundation.h>`.

Comment: For Swift3 I just imported the Foundation.h in the the bridging header and it works. thank you @Sourav

Answer (score 3):

The C standard since C99 defines `_Bool` as a keyword, along with `_True` and `_False`. `stdint.h` provides macros with the C++ names `bool`, etc. to map to these keywords.

Note that `BOOL` and `bool` are different names, as C is case-sensitive. So you should change `BOOL` to `bool`. **If** that is not possible (e.g. if you use foreign libraries),

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#define BOOL bool
```

Comment: Actually, since BOOL and bool are different types, your #define BOOL bool is asking for serious trouble, bugs that you cannot find etc. Among other things, bool and BOOL can have different sizes. But only sometimes. Which means writing to a bool* instead of a BOOL* can crash your program.

Comment: @gnasher729: Of course, that depends on wether they are compatible. However, who the heck names something incompatible `BOOL`?

Answer (score 0):

It was broken Apple software.

Apple disregarded my 3.2.6 projects settings and decided to use the LLVM 3.0 suite rather than GCC 4.2. Previously (under Xcode 3.2.6), I had specifically set the project to use GCC due to my extensive use of GCC warnings and flags.

After I changed 'Build Settings' -> 'Compile for C/C++/Objective' back to GCC 4.2, it worked.

Comment: You are using GCC 4.2? In that case it's not Apple's broken software, it's your broken project. GCC hasn't been supported for years. You are seriously not doing yourself any favours by insisting to use GCC.